# Garageband is *always* recording internal computer audio

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone, garageband

I'm making a very simple recording using the built-in microphone. However, even though I'm wearing headphones, garageband is recording the internal audio along with the microphone input. That means, for exemple, that the metronome and the other tracks I've already recorded get recorded into every new track no matter what I do. Here are my system's details:

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
MacOS Catalina v10.15.3

Thanks!

Comment: How have you set the audio input/output settings in GarageBand? Have you installed any audio routing software like SoundFlower or Loopback or Audio Hijack?